# Does an object in a v-shaped channel experience static friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

As the title states, I was wondering if an object that is at rest in a horizontal, v-shape channel like the one in this diagram would experience static friction:

[image: ball in a v-shaped channel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't. Because the net force on it is zero.

Consider a frictionless case. The object will be at rest. Meaning net force is zero. So in the given case no need for frictional force to act.

Comment: So is it in freefall?

Comment: No, reaction force from opposites side and gravitational force balances out. Each interaction between objects is not necessarily done only through frictional force.

Comment: A ball at rest on ground has no frictional force acting on it. It's simply a perpendicular reaction force.